# Comparing Columns for changes using a custom function on a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to apply a function that looks for changes in values pairs between two columns. However i'm unsure how to compare the data in a way that I return a specific value. e.g ( sally gee and vanilla are entered into the database first and therefore they are paired, but now the sally gee's flavor in row three has been changed to chocolate <--- I want to return the row that this occurs )

**Test DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
['id 1','sally gee','vanilla'], # value pair sally gee and vanilla
['id 2','sally gee','vanilla'], 
['id 3', 'sally gee','Chocolate']]), # change in value pair, flag !

columns=['idNum', 'name', 'flavor'])
```

**Custom Function Pseudo Code**

```
def find_mismatch(df):
   if df.groupby(['idNum','name']).nunique() > 1: # if there is two flavors for one person then return 
      return idNum,name
```

**Edits after answer**

```
     idNum    name       flavor     change
--  -------  ---------  ---------  --------
 0  id 1     sally gee  vanilla    NaN # intialized
 1  id 2     sally gee  vanilla    vanilla # correct / match
 2  id 3     sally gee  Chocolate  vanilla # -- change occurs here / no match
 3  id 4     sally gee  vanilla    Chocolate # -- correct because original is vanilla
 4  id 5     sally gee  vanilla    vanilla # -- correct

return 2  id 3     sally gee  Chocolate  vanilla
```

I believe we are making progress, I revised the df to
show the change in flavor as an error. I essentially
would like to pull out row 2 when that change occurs
and that's it. In a automated format using a custom
function. As of now I display all the rows and have to
manually check I just want to get that row where changes
occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what you want to accomplish, so it would be helpful if you provided expected output for your input

But if you want to do what I am guessing you want to do, you can do this

```
df[df[['name','flavor']].duplicated(keep = False)]
```

this will print all rows of your dataframe where `'name'` and `'flavor'` appear more than once; for your dataframe it will produce

```
    idNum   name        flavor
0   id 1    sally gee   vanilla
1   id 2    sally gee   vanilla
```

If you want to find rows where there are 3 or more matches (as your pseudocode indicates but it is not entirely clear as your dataframe has no such rows) you can use a different version of the above where you can set `find_n_matches` to whatever number you want:

```
find_n_matches = 2
df[df.groupby(['name','flavor']).transform('count')['idNum']>=find_n_matches]
```

You can wrap it as a function if you wish:

```
def find_matched_rows(df, find_n_matches = 2):
    return df[df.groupby(['name','flavor']).transform('count')['idNum']>=find_n_matches]
```

### Edit after clarifications added to the question

Now with the question clarified, the code below selects rows in the dataframe when `flavor` changes for each `name`

This creates a column `change` that highlights (sets to `True`) the rows where the change occurred

```
df2 = df.groupby(['name']).apply(lambda d:d.assign(change = (d['flavor'] != d['flavor'].shift()) )).reset_index(drop = True)
df2
```

prints

```
    idNum    name       flavor     change
--  -------  ---------  ---------  --------
 0  id 1     sally gee  vanilla    True
 1  id 2     sally gee  vanilla    False
 2  id 3     sally gee  Chocolate  True
```

Now we can select only 'new' rows when the flavor changed, for each name,

```
df2[df2['change']]
```

output

```
    idNum   name        flavor      change
0   id 1    sally gee   vanilla     True
2   id 3    sally gee   Chocolate   True
```

### Edit 2, next iteration

How about this

```
df['original flavor'] = df.groupby(['name'])['flavor'].transform('first')
df[df['original flavor'] != df['flavor']]
```

this will pull out rows, per person, where the `'flavor'` is different from the `'original flavor'` which is defined to be the first flavor for that person

Comment: I do apologize for the unclear question, It was very late when I posted it. Evaluating it now I do see the adjustments I would make to my question. The intended result I seek is to return the row with more than 1 unique 'flavor' in this case. @piterbarg

Comment: @JeremyCruzado pls check out my edit in the answer, is this what you are after?

Comment: Thank you so much for working on this with me, we are making progress however the code provided displays the changes but for all rows. I would like to just extract the one row that the change appears. Please see the adjustments made in the question.

Comment: @JeremyCruzado there is also change in row 3 from chocolate back to vanilla, why is that excluded? it is frankly getting more confusing.

Comment: The actual data that i am testing this on is returning the rows in that manner. I did this to try and clarify the question even more, i apologize if i caused confusion. Essential I just want to select the row in which the change occurs. e.g( flavor is initialized to vanilla and then appears as chocolate I would just want to select that specific row when it occurs )

Comment: @pitterbarg You are a genius, this is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: @JeremyCruzado glad we got to the bottom of it. consider marking  the answer accepted per the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers